# VBa to clear all activex checkboxes in Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to create a button to clear all the activex check-boxes in a .docm file, but nothing seems to work. I saw many posts in the fórum, but none seems to work. Can anyone help me? Obs.: the original file have at least 30 check boxes and I don't want to type all the check-boxes names.
See the code below and the example file attached

Ps.: I tried ThisDocument.Fields; Me.Control and many others.

See attached image as example: [ActiveX CheckBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wVFC.png)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Ctl As MSForms.Control

    For Each Ctl In ThisDocument.FormFields
        If Ctl.Name = "CheckBox" Then Ctl.Value = False
    Next Ctl
End Sub
```

Comment: I found this: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4302-excel-uncheck-all-checkboxes.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that code is for Excel, and I'm working with Word.

Comment: You need to specificy what kind of checkboxes are used in the document. Word has at least four different possibilities. What commands were used to create these checkboxes?

Comment: I only know 2 forms of check-boxes (sorry for my lack of knowledge), but is an ActiveX Check-box (see image attached). I'm sorry but didn't find a way to attached the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many tests, the code below solved my problem:

```
Private Sub Limpar_Click()
Dim iShp As InlineShape
For Each iShp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
  If iShp.OLEFormat.ClassType = "Forms.CheckBox.1" Then
                iShp.OLEFormat.Object.Value = False
            End If
    Next
End Sub
```